# Realm: create relationships by ids

Tags: java, android, orm, realm

Assume that I have several realm objects (tables) with many connections between them, and I don't yet have all the objects pre populated.

I want to be able to create relationships by their ids (primary keys).

For example, I have JSON file with an object that has a list of another object's ids (not the actual object, although that another object is already exists in the realm db), I want to be able to populate those into objects directly without having to query them first.

How is that possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in order to set an object link, you'll need to query the object to set it. Otherwise just setting an unmanaged object will overwrite the old one with default values.

Comment: Can you add some example data to illustrate what you mean? I dont fully understand

Comment: just to know, did u find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Realm is designed to be an object database without impedance mistach that could happen from mapping Java objects to an entry in table. Relation in Realm is specifically handled to adhere the principle above.

For example, one can describe relationship between object in following.

```
public class ObjectA extends RealmObject {
    ...
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    ...
}

public class ObjectB extends RealmObject {
    ...
    private RealmList<ObjectA> entries;
    ...
}
```

The relation you want, i.e. relation by primarykey id, seems much close to relational databases and it is not supported.